# Storing time and date as UTC in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, datetime, utc

I've been reading a ton of stuff on SO about how to store date/time as UTC in the DB...but I'm still really confused. What I gathered is to use `gmdate()` to generate the date and time as UTC in my PHP script (I use Wordpress's $wpdb->insert to insert into the DB). My set up in MySQL is a field called timestamp and it is of the format DATETIME with no Length/Values or Default specified. However, when I use the function below, the value that gets stored is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

```
$datetime = gmdate(r);
$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'fd_transactions', array('timestamp' => $datetime));
```

Comment: The format you used for `gmdate()` is `Y-m-d H:i:s`?

Comment: @frz3993 I think so, yes. Why?

Comment: The manual for gmdate/[date](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) says that `r` produces a string like `Example: Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200`

Comment: @VolkerK So then should I change the function I am using in PHP to something else or change the field to `VARCHAR` in the table?

Comment: `gmdate(r);` will produce error. It should be `gmdate('r')`. And that will give you as what @VolkerK commented. To insert correctly into mysql datetime field the format should be `Y-m-d H:i:s` not `r`.